# get multiple var in a function by find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a calculation with two selected option and input. Like when you select 'a' and 'd' then input=1 it give result 75. I wrote a jquery code but it doesn't work . I can't find any error on console .Please check it below :

```js
$(window).load(function(){
function doStuff() {
var uone= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'a';
var utwo= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'b';
var uthree= $("#ud").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'c';
var bone= $("#bt").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'd';
var btwo= $("#bt").children(":selected").attr("id") == 'e';
var getvalue;

if ($(uone).find(bone)) {
    getvalue = 75;
}
if ($(uone).find(btwo)) {
    getvalue = 70;
}
if ($(utwo).find(bone))  {
    getvalue = 81;
}
if ($(uthree).find(bone))  {
    getvalue = 79;
}

var shw = $('#inputamount').val();
var total = getvalue * shw ;
$("#totalop").html(total);
}
$("#inputamount").on('keyup', doStuff);
$("#ud").on('change', doStuff);
$("#bt").on('change', doStuff);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sucompn" id="ud">
    <option id="a">a</option>
    <option id="b">b</option>
    <option id="c">c</option>
</select>
<select name="ducompn" id="bt">
    <option id="d">d</option>
    <option id="e">e</option>
</select>
<input autocomplete="off" name="inputamount" id="inputamount" value="" type="text">
<span id="totalop"></span>
```

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/90t9pe42/?

Comment: But im kinda unsure why your using this `$(uone).find(bone)` what do you want to achive with this?

Comment: something if select id a and select id d then getvalue*input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use id use value for the options

```
<select name="sucompn" id="ud">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
<select name="ducompn" id="bt">
  <option value="d">d</option>
  <option value="e">e</option>
 </select>
```

then you can get the values like

```
var selectedUd = $("#ud").val();
var selectedBt = $("#bt").val();
```

then you can do:

```
var uone = selectedUd== 'a';
var utwo = selectedUd == 'b';
var uthree = selectedUd == 'c';

var bone =selectedBt == 'd';
var btwo =selectedBt== 'e';
```

then (I don't really know what you wanted to do here ) but you could do things like

```
var getValue;
if(uone && bone) getvALUE =75;
else if(uone && btwo) getValue = 70; 
else if(utwo && bone) getValue = 81; 

...here rthe rest of posibilities

var shw = $('#inputamount').val();
var total = getvalue * shw;
$("#totalop").html(total);
```

Here is the Plunker - [Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/kvPX776V2hBZgM3zVHGr?p=preview)

Comment: I was trying to apply your idea and it's worked I just used `else if(uone && btwo)` inside `if($(uone).find(btwo)` thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You have defined `var getValue;`, but use in code another variable `getvalue = 75;`(`getValue` and `getvalue` are not the same). Probably you have undefined variable and this problem usually yields no console info.